# Caddy Server + Docker + Traefik returns "404 Site domain.com is not served on this interface"

Tags: docker, traefik, hugo, caddy

I'm using Hugo Framework to play around continuous deployment. I created an image containing Caddy server, Hugo and the test project I used for my tests, sent it to my server that runs Traefik and started the image.

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:latest

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install git curl -y
ADD https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases/download/v0.42.2/hugo_0.42.2_Linux-64bit.deb /tmp/hugo.deb
RUN dpkg -i /tmp/hugo.deb && rm /tmp/hugo.deb
RUN curl https://getcaddy.com | bash -s personal
RUN chown root:root /usr/local/bin/caddy && chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/caddy
RUN mkdir /srv/app
WORKDIR /srv/app
COPY . ./
RUN git clone https://github.com/RealOrangeOne/hugo-theme-revealjs.git themes/hugo-theme-revealjs
RUN hugo
EXPOSE 2015
CMD ["caddy"]
```

And here is the "docker-compose.yml" that runs my project on my server:

```
my_project:
  image: some_registry/my_project
  ports:
    - "2015:2015"
  labels:
    - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:subdomain.domain.me"
```

I almost forgot, here is my Caddyfile:

```
localhost:2015
root /srv/app/public
```

The image runs without problem, but when reaching `subdomain.domain.me`, I get the following message:

> 404 Site subdomain.domain.me is not served on this interface

However, running `curl http://localhost:2015` prints my project's HTML on my server.

So... I think the problem comes from Caddy, since I have no problem when using Apache, and about 5 other of my projects use Traefik without problem.

My question is: how should I edit my Caddyfile so that I don't have this problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: If Caddy gets a request on port 2015 for a `Host` header value other than "localhost" it will give you that error; make sure your reverse proxy is sending it to `localhost` and not some other hostname.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caddy is looking for a request looking for localhost:2015.  I would guess that you are forwarding a request to the machine but not to localhost.

Start Caddy with the -log path/to/log.log parameter and you may see what the request is, or try

```
:2015
root /srv/app/public
```

This will serve any request coming in on port 2015.

Comment: Wow I didn't know it was possible to do so, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Container networking requires that your app inside the container listen on all interfaces. Docker cannot reach the loopback interface inside your container from outside of the container, including published ports and container to container networking.

If you want to limit access to this port on your docker host, you can limit what interfaces docker publishes the port:

```
version: '3'
services:
  my_project:
    image: some_registry/my_project
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:2015:2015"
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:subdomain.domain.me"
```

Inside the container, follow Toby's advice to adjust the caddy configuration by removing "localhost" from your Caddyfile.